# Capturing hex data packets with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to figure out the best way to capture data packets present in a string that also contains otherwise unwanted characters.
The data packets are in hex, typically grouped into bytes with white space in-between. The packets vary in length and are delimited at the beginning and end with "10" and "10 03" respectively. Thus, a bit of text with the packet in it may look like this:

```
gibberish 10 01 23 AB CD EF 10 03 gibberish
```

I can get a regex to capture the string of hex bytes easily enough, but without accounting for the delimiters multiple hex packets can become one, or unwanted characters at the beginning or end that happen to look like hex can be lumped in with the packet. How can I get a regex to account for the delimiters?
I can think of ways around this without using regular expressions, but that doesn't seem like it would be as efficient.

Comment: Show what you are using now and how it doesn't work

Comment: If you want a regex to capture hex part, I think you can use a regex like `10\s*(([\dA-F]{2} )+)\s*10 03` ;).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the gibberish at the beginning is referring to the memory address. It is a contiguous string, without any white-space. Hence, use `\S+` to capture that.

Since the hex data will be delimited by `10` at the beginning and `10 03` at the end, use them:

```
^\S+ (10 (?:[0-9a-f]{2} )+10 03)
```

A demo [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pJ2xQ7/1).

PS: You'll have to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag.

Comment: That looks like it does the trick. What I had looked very much like that, but I was unfamiliar with the concept of a "non-capturing group." and thus missed that.